# Docker image failed to install node with chrome browser

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, dockerfile, docker-registry

I am trying to build docker image with node as a base image along with google chrome however it is failing to create a image.
Thanks!

```
FROM node:14.17.1
RUN echo "deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib non-free" /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

ARG CHROME_VERSION="google-chrome-stable"
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
  && echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list \
  && apt-get update -qqy \
  && apt-get -y install ${CHROME_VERSION:-google-chrome-stable} vim curl bash \
  && rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/apt/*

RUN bash -v
CMD 'cat'
```

Exception

```
                                                                                                                                                             
 > [5/7] RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -   && echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list   && apt-get update -qqy   && apt-get -y install google-chrome-stable vim curl bash   && rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list   && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/apt/*:
#8 0.292 Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)
#8 0.422 gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -   && echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list   && apt-get update -qqy   && apt-get -y install ${CHROME_VERSION:-google-chrome-stable} vim curl bash   && rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list   && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/apt/*]: exit code: 2
```

I have tried to download the chrome driver by downloading and install and also tried with FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:14.17.1 still not able to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your repository configuration or better yet, use a newer base image, example node:14.21.

To update your repository configuration, change deb.debian.org to archive.debian.org in lines referencing in /etc/apt/sources.list